# Not able to open the browser in Bamboo While running a selenium script

Tags: selenium, continuous-integration, bamboo

I am trying to run the selenium script generated from selenium IDE in Bamboo using Charlotte. Everything is working fine. But it is unable to open the browser.

In the log its showing that

> *Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 12654 Only local
>   connections are allowed.*

But its not opening the browser.
Can anybody suggest me what should i do so that the browser will open.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Due to restricted privileges, the system will restrict chrome browser to open.

Follow below step if it works for you.
got to Bamboo installation directory,

```
C:\Program Files\Bamboo
```

Open cmd there and execute 'BambooConsole.bat'

```
C:\Program Files\Bamboo>BambooConsole.bat
```